# Problem with probability of hypothesis testing

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Three coins are tossed. If all three show tails, $H_0$ is rejected,
otherwise, $H_0$ is not rejected. Using this procedure, what is the probability of committing a Type II error?

I have that $1 - [P(\text{get tail 1st toss}|H_1\text{ true})*P(\text{get tail 2nd toss}|H_1\text{ true})*P(\text{get tail 3rd toss}|H_1\text{ true})]$

But I am not sure of this $1 - ((1/8)(1/8)(1/8))$

Comment: What are $H_0$ and $H_a$?

Comment: That is the problem I thin H0 is fair Ha Unfair

Comment: A type II error is the event that you don't reject $H_0$ when $H_0$ is false. If you don't know the true probability of getting heads then you can't solve the problem

Comment: Well are coins so the probability of not getting 3 tails is 3/4

Comment: @CarlaSandoval That is when $H_0$ is true.  We need the conditional probability when $H_0$ is false (ie the coin is biased).

Comment: if Ha is true p=1

Comment: Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Something is missing in the text. Assuming that the null hypothesis is

$$H_0: \theta_0\leq\frac{1}{2}$$

Against

$$H_1: \theta_1 >\frac{1}{2}$$

Where $\theta$ is the probability to get tail, type II error is

$$\beta=1-\mathbb{P}[\text{TTT}|\theta_1]=1-\theta_1^3$$

Observe that $\beta$ decreases when $\theta_1$ increases in the Interval $\left(\frac{1}{2};1\right]$ as it must be.